# Error running puppet

Tags: rvm, puppet

I've just installed puppet 3.8.4 on OSX 10.5.5.  When running `puppet --version` from the command line to check the installation I get the following error:

```
macbook-MBP:~ richard$ puppet --version
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _rb_ary_new_from_values
  Referenced from: /Users/richard/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/psych-2.0.15/lib/psych.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _rb_ary_new_from_values
  Referenced from: /Users/richard/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/psych-2.0.15/lib/psych.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Most probably something is wrong with your ruby environment

Comment: Many thanks - any ideas where I should start checking?

Comment: No. Try to use the default ruby installation that comes with your OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puppet `3.x` has [no support](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/platforms.html#ruby-versions) for Ruby `2.2`.

You will have to either

- try and install Ruby `2.1`
- try and install Puppet `4`

Puppet 4 has limited compatibility with 3, so going for an alternate Ruby will likely be easier, depending on your existing infrastructure.